# Jquery DOM modification not preserved on forward and back

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am able to update a DOM element (button) successfully on user action - when clicking the 'add favorite' button, the favorite is added and the button changes to 'delete favorite'.

The button is updated as follows:

```
$("#favorite_box").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'favorite' )) %>")
```

The partial is:

```
<% if current_user.favorites("Style").where(:favoritable_id=>@style.id).empty? == true
%>
  <%= link_to "<i class = \"icon-star-empty\"></i> Add Favorite".html_safe, "/fav_style/#{@style.id}", :remote=>true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "<i class = \"icon-star\"></i> Delete Favorite".html_safe, "/delete_fav_style/#{@style.id}", :remote=>true %>
<% end %>
```

**So the problem is, when I click another link, and then click the back button, the button reflects the initial load state, and does not reflect the last Jquery DOM update.**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Of course it doesn't preserve the changes. jQuery is a library for a client-side language...

Comment: Well, I realize this, but how do I fix it?

Comment: How is the content on the page generated in the first place? You'd have to use Ruby to store the DOM change, and then serve it up from the server side.

Comment: Well, is there any way to force reload on forward and back entry to the page?

Comment: Why would that solve your problem?

Comment: Because the partial would be called again and the logic would cause the proper state of the button to be displayed

Comment: I guess I could just put a validation for favorite uniqueness in the model and forget about the issue.

Comment: That's certainly going to be the easier approach...